Debezium Azure SQL MERGE SQL queries are logged as Delete + Insert queries in CDC
While doing an update using MERGE statement on a CDC enabled table, it logs two records with: _operation 1: DELETE and _operation 2: INSERT. It should actually log as 3[Before Update] and 4[After Update]. It only happens, when any indexed column is in MERGE's update statement.
We are using debezium to consume events from CDC, at present on any Update on database two events are triggered from debezium. One delete and another create instead of update.
So do we need to implement custom logic in debezium to aggregate DELETE/CREATE event and consider it as UPDATE?
Any option solution from debezium side?
